# C++ template function inside a non-template class

Tags: c++, templates

I am looking to start putting in templates in my c++ class code but I have come across a situation I have not experienced before. Basically I have a non-templates class but only 1 function in the class I need to be templated.

```
class example
{
 public:
 example();
 ~example();
 <template T> templatefunction(T);
 nontemplatefunction(string x);
};
```

Is this possible? If so, is it a common solution or am I looking at templates completely in error?

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Comment: If you fix the syntax it would be fine to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As people have noted in the comments, there's no problem doing so.

One aspect to watch out for is where to put the definition of the method `templatefunction`. For the time being (see the [ISO cpp FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-class-defn-from-decl)), you should consider placing it in the header file, which is different than what you'd probably do with the definition of the other methods. Thus you'd have `example.hpp`:

```
class example
{
 public:
 example();
 ~example();
 template<typename T> void templatefunction(T);
 void nontemplatefunction(string x);
};

template<typename T> void example::templatefunction(T)
{

}
```

and then `example.cpp`:

```
example::example(){}

void example::nontemplatefunction(string x)
{

}
```